# Content slider with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a slider from below website

http://callmenick.com/post/responsive-content-slider

This slider is responsive but i would like to know how to make the slider main div height auto adjust depending on the content.

This is the slider code

JS:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.cslide = function() {

        this.each(function() {

            var slidesContainerId = "#"+($(this).attr("id"));

            var len = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide").size();     // get number of slides
            var slidesContainerWidth = len*100+"%";                     // get width of the slide container
            var slideWidth = (100/len)+"%";                             // get width of the slides

            // set slide container width
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").css({
                width : slidesContainerWidth,
                visibility : "visible"
            });

            // set slide width
            $(".cslide-slide").css({
                width : slideWidth
            });

            // add correct classes to first and last slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").last().addClass("cslide-last");
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").first().addClass("cslide-first cslide-active");

            // initially disable the previous arrow cuz we start on the first slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");

            // if first slide is last slide, hide the prev-next navigation
            if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active.cslide-first").hasClass("cslide-last")) {           
                $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev-next").css({
                    display : "block"
                });
            }

            // handle the next clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i+1;
                var slideLeft = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").next(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideLeft
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) && $(".cslide-prev").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });

            // handle the prev clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i-1;
                var slideRight = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").prev(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideRight
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) && $(".cslide-next").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });



        });

        // return this for chainability
        return this;

    }

}(jQuery));
```

HTML

```
<section id="cslide-slides" class="cslide-slides-master clearfix">
            <div class="cslide-prev-next clearfix">
                <span class="cslide-prev">prev slide</span>
                <span class="cslide-next">next slide</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">
                <div class="cslide-slide">
                    <h2>This is slide 1</h2>
                    <p>Slide 1 Content.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-slide">
                    <h2>This is slide 2</h2>
                    <p>Slide 2 Content.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-slide">
                    <h2>This is slide 3</h2>
                    <p>Slide 3 Content.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-slide">
                    <h2>This is slide 4</h2>
                    <p>Slide 4 Content.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-slide">
                    <h2>This is slide 5</h2>
                    <p>Slide 5 Content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- /sliding content section -->
```

if the content is long in next or previous slides it will adjust fine. issue is cslide-slide parent div which is cslide-slides-master is not adjusting if the next slide content is shorter then the previous content.

I tried below code with no luck at all

```
$('.cslide-next').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $('.cslide-slides-master'),
        child = parent.children('.cslide-slide');

    if (child.height() > parent.height()) {
        parent.height(child.height());
    }
});
```

Can anyone point me how to fix this issue?